# Adding .min suffix when compiling multiple scss file using npm sass

Tags: npm, sass, npm-scripts

I have many scss files and I'm compiling them to multiple css files using `npm sass`.

My package.json file is like this:

```
sass --style=compressed website/assets/scss:website/assets/css
```

This works fine and saves compressed versions in my website/assets/css/ folder. But I'd like two things to happen.

1. When saving the compressed version add .min to the file names e.g. style.min.css
2. Also save a non-compressed file in the same folder (without .min suffix).

How do I adjust my script in the package.json to achieve this?

I'm guessing I need two lines added (one compressed and one not)?

No idea how to do the .min suffix when saving multiple files. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Part two is easy enough to do. Just add another line to the package.json file

```
"sass": "sass website/assets/scss:website/assets/css"
```

In the end, I had to use gulp. Everything was achievable easy enough using gulp.